# Issue with "grading" exercice from C programming language textbook, Joy of C

Tags: c

I try to code with the given code from C programming language textbook, Joy of C, I typed exactly according to the book. This code seem perfect to me and it works fine, except at avg_score which won't compute and display correctly.

It's always displayed 0, so I think the problem might be caused by

```
total_score = total_score + next_score;
```

doesn't work properly.

I would like to thank in advance for anybody who give me a hand, especially who know what the cause is.

edit1. I sorry very much for my mistake. I intend to ask for avg_score, not total score. I did check the cause and it appear to be total_score is alway 0.

edit2. my expecting result is something like the following (may not exact)

**Example Input:**

```
Score? 91
91 - PASS
Score? 70
70 - PASS
Score? 69
69 - FAIL
Score? h
3 score entered, 2 pass
average score is 76.67
```

**Source Code**:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>
#define PASSING_SCORE 70

int main()
{
    int next_score;
    int n;
    int score_count;
    int pass_count;
    int fail_count;
    int avg_score;
    int total_score;

    score_count = 0;
    pass_count = 0;
    fail_count = 0;
    total_score = 0;

    printf("Score?");
    n = scanf("%i",&next_score);

    while(n==1)
    {
        score_count = score_count + 1;  
        total_score = total_score + next_score;
        if (next_score >= PASSING_SCORE)    
        {
            printf("%i - PASS\n",next_score);
            pass_count = pass_count + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%i - FAIL\n",next_score);
            fail_count = fail_count + 1;
        }
        printf("Score?");
        n = scanf("%i",&next_score);
    }

    if (score_count == 0)
        avg_score = 0;
    else
        avg_score = total_score/score_count;

    printf("\n%i score entered, %i pass, %ifail.\n",
        score_count,pass_count,fail_count);
    printf("average score is %.2f\n",avg_score);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You make no effort at all to display `total_score` anywhere in the code you posted, so it's not surprising it doesn't display correctly. Did you mean to include it in one of the `printf` calls and forget? You probably should also change `avg_score` to a floating point value, because an average of < 1 will display as `0` using integer math.

Comment: A good opportunity to learn basic debugging skills.  Place more `printf` statements in your code to see how many times you loop and to print out the intermediate values you calculate.

Comment: I did try printf on many place in code to display total_score value. those displayed code is original. by the way, all total_score that I code also display zero too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at your compiler warnings : `avg_score` is declared as an integer, but you print with `%.2f`.

You probably meant to declare it as a floating point number : `double` would work. Or print it as an integer with `%d`, I'm not sure what your code example is about.

**EDIT:**

To correctly compute your average (as commented by @Mike), you should cast one of the quotient operands to `double` :

```
avg_score = total_score/(double)score_count;
```

If not, you would get the integer quotient.

Comment: Yes, and don't forget to cast `total_score` to `double` before dividing by `score_count`, if you care about the fractional part of `avg_score`.

Comment: absolutely (I don't have th book in hand, I'm not sure what this is suppose to show to the reader)

Comment: to my surprise! it's also one of my mistake, thank you!!.. but avg_score still not displayed properly.

Comment: It's worked!! after I do as what both of you (quantdev and Mike Holt) suggested. I changed those count to integer and score to double and all work fine. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

By changing two lines of code, I believe I have the correct output:

1. Declare `avg_score` as a double.

   ```
   double avg_score;
   ```
2. Cast `total_score` to a double when calculating `avg_score` so that we don't use integer division:

   ```
   if (score_count == 0)
       avg_score = 0;
   else
       avg_score = (double) total_score/score_count;
   ```

Let's try running it with these fixes:

```
[8:59pm][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] ./foo
Score?91
91 - PASS
Score?70
70 - PASS
Score?69
69 - FAIL
Score?h

3 score entered, 2 pass, 1fail.
average score is 76.67
```

Comment: thank you very much. I wish I can accept both answer :]